# Error Master-Child record save with .net Blazor (Core hosted) Server App

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

`enter code here`I had successfully done CRUD for student table with id,name,birthdate,gender but when i tried to made entry with a child table named studentCourse having multiple entries for studentCourse it was not working.

I have added one Multiselect Dropdown for StudentCourse but it was retriving data from api but not binding

any one have an idea how to make it possible with child tables.
Here is my code

```
 @page "/studentpost"
    @using BlazorApp.Shared.Models
    @using BlazorApp.Shared.Enums
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    @inject HttpClient Http


    <h3>Add Student Details</h3>

    <div>
        <EditForm Model="@student">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            <table class="form-group">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Student Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@student.Name" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => student.Name)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pt-5">
                    <td>
                        <label for="Email" class="control-label">BirthDate</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@student.BirthDate" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => student.BirthDate)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pt-5">
                    <td>
                        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Gender</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <InputSelect id="DdlGender" @bind-Value="student.Gender">
                            <option value="0">-- Select Gender --</option>
                            <option value="@Gender.Type.Male">@Gender.Type.Male.ToString()</option>
                            <option value="@Gender.Type.Female">@Gender.Type.Female.ToString()</option>
                            <option value="@Gender.Type.TransGender">@Gender.Type.TransGender.ToString()</option>
                        </InputSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => student.Gender)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pt-5">
                    <td>
                        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Course</label>
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <InputSelect id="DdlCourse" @bind-Value="courses">
                            <option value="0">-- Select Gender --</option>
                            @foreach (var itm in courses)
                            {
                                <option value="@itm.Id">@itm.CourseName.ToString()</option>
                            }
                        </InputSelect>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pt-5">
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(async ()=> await AddStudent())">Save</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="Cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditForm>
    </div>

    @code {
        Student student = null;
        Course[] courses=null;
        //protected override void OnInitialized()
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            student = new Student() {Gender=Gender.Type.Female ,BirthDate = DateTime.Now };
            courses=await Http.GetJsonAsync<Course[]>("course"); 
        }

        public async Task<Course[]> GetCourses()
        {
            return await Http.GetJsonAsync<Course[]>("course");
        }
        void BackToList()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/fetchstudent");
        }

        void Cancel()
        {
            BackToList();
        }


        protected async Task AddStudent()
        {
            await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "student/add", student);
            BackToList();
        }

        //private void GenderChanged(UIChangeEventArgs e)
        //{

        //}
    }
```

With Shared Project I am having model from DB

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required ]
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage ="Name must be within 150 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1,3)]
        public Gender.Type Gender { get; set; }

       // public List<int> CourseIds { get; set; }
    }

 public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
    }
```

In Context I have registed this model

```
public class CoreDemoContext : DbContext
    {


        //public CoreDemoContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDemoContext> options) : base(options)
        //{

        //}

        public CoreDemoContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StudentCourse> StudentCourse { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=RITA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CoreDemo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@bind-Value` should be the selected item and not the array:

```
<InputSelect id="DdlCourse" @bind-Value="selectedCourse">
```

and in `@code`

```
Course selectedCourse = null;
```

Comment: please review this again i had provide details for better understanding

Comment: `<InputSelect>` can only select ONE item, not multiple. That means the `@bind-Value` has to be ONE course like @bind-Value="student.course".

Comment: For MultiSelect what is the solution?

Comment: Some control libraries have multiselect dropdowns, for example [Radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/dropdown) or else you have to build it yourself in javascript.